# The ${\cal M}_{if}$ that appears in the Feynman diagrams - Are they probability ranges?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, notation, feynman-diagrams

${\cal M}_{if}$ are probability amplitudes? This right here

[image]

that this on top of each diagram, Why is it you cancel my questions that I asked anything special this is not cool I just wanted a help and so all the time canceling my questions, if someone has available can answer my Doubt?

Comment: *Why is it you guys cancel my questions* One of your previous questions was closed for being *unclear*. It would also take much of a course in quantum field theory to answer that question, so it was inappropriate for PSE’s format.

Comment: This "Feynman diagram for beginners" might show the way to understand them ( a long way) https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04182

Answer (score 1):

They are [probability *amplitudes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude#Amplitudes_in_operators), not probability *ranges*. They are also called “matrix elements”. They are complex numbers, and their squared magnitudes are related to the probability that the initial state $i$ in the Feynman diagram becomes the final state $f$.

Comment: Thank you Could you answer me other questions?

Comment: Ndo not know if aki will answer more will have some feynman diagrams that I do not know the physical interpretation that are that of the star, the x with a ball around and 1PI,And the diagram that looks like the loop plus is painted gray

Comment: @ian maybe you should find an introductory text in QFT or a bridge text between quantum mechanics and QFT first depending on your level of instruction in the topic.

Comment: These diagrams I know what they are and how they work mathematically and i've seen particle physics anymore I don't know what it would be for example now using the proper names of the diagrams that I don't know the physical meaning that I imagine you know, Counterterm,operator or current, all one particle Irreducible contributions, generic amplitude, alternative generic amplitude These diagrams do not know how they would apply in real life in a physical /experimental form

Comment: Different and something for example that describes the interaction of fermi

Comment: @ian *Could you answer me other questions?* I only see one other question. It is currently closed, so no one can answer it.

Comment: @ian your other question shows some components/parts  of feynman diagrams,   The physical meaning of a Feynman diagram comes from the incoming real particles interacting and the outgoing particles from the interaction. The in between dtawins are representing part of the mathematics within the integration implied in the use of Feynman diagrams, There is no physical meaning separate from the whole diagram. There is a mathematical meaning/reason for them . Before Feynman invented his diagrams, the same integrations would be carried out in a much more difficult way.

Comment: The diagrams organized the integrations so that the perturbation expansion used to solve a scattering or a decay becomes easy to mathematically manipulate. The diagrams you show in the other question are internal diagrams used in  higher order terms in the series expansion of the probability of scattering or decay. If you are serious in studying  physics at this level start with something like this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04182.pdf